# How to implement jpeg progressive image on web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jpeg

I am working on website([winni.in](https://www.winni.in/cake-delivery-in-goa)), Which is based on Java, Html, Javascript. I want to implement render progressive image on page load. But i don't know much more idea about it. I have seen and read these links:

***http://pooyak.com/p/progjpeg/***
[image]

> https://blog.codinghorror.com/progressive-image-rendering/
>
> http://pooyak.com/p/progjpeg/
>
> https://jmperezperez.com/medium-image-progressive-loading-placeholder/

I have read above links but i did not get how to implements progressive image concept. I am a front end developer, It is possible from front-end or back-end. I don't know. This concept also using by facebook.

Comment: Never use java on the web. The support is very close to 0.

Comment: I think, this is best on web still i am searching. But who need urgently then see link.(convert image into progressive image with  ImageMagick).http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127266/change-jpeg-into-progressive-jpeg-image

Answer (score 1):

You have to save/convert images as progressive images , you cas use photoshop or any other images processor for this, you need to check :'interlaced' and 'progressive' check box while saving image.
Note: saving images as progressive  may increase images  size around 10%-20% .