# Change Jpeg into progressive Jpeg Image

Tags: image, jpeg, progressive-download, progressive

I want to convert from base line Jpeg image to progressive Jpeg image.
 There are 10,000 images stored in my Disk.
 I tried one website but it is changing one at time.http://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/compress-image.php
But I want to convert them in bulk.
 Is there any online tools or some programming techniques?
 Then, let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can do that with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows.

**Make a copy before experimenting on a small batch of images!**

You can do a whole directory full of JPEGs like this:

```
mogrify -interlace plane *.jpg
```

Or, if you want to do one at a time:

```
convert input.jpg -interlace plane output.jpg
```

Or, if you want to do a whole directory and every subdirectory on Linux/OSX:

```
find . -iname \*.jpg -exec convert {} -interlace plane {} \;
```

---

Or, you can use **GNU Parallel** on Linux/OSX if you want to get the job done faster. That goes like this:

```
parallel -X mogrify -interlace plane ::: *.jpg
```

If you want the output in a directory called "progressive", use:

```
mkdir progressive
parallel -X mogrify -path progressive -interlace plane ::: *.jpg
```

---

You can also do it with **jpegtran** which is miles easier to install:

```
jpegtran -copy none -progressive input.jpg output.jpg
```

Comment: How would you use GNU Parallel?

Comment: @nadermx I have added that in for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Windows** user here - I like to use a tool called [irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com/) which I have been using over 10 years now, it's a 3MB freeware and can do many sorts of (batch) modifications on images, some in lossless quality. powerful stuff.

I also use & recommend [xnview](https://www.xnview.com) which is available for **MAC** also and also has a **command-line** tool.

Simply view the JPEG you wish to convert and choose "save as" from the top left "file" menu and save using "progressive".